# Boostrap 4 alpha 6 - row inside card behavior

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and noticed a strange behavior when using a grid inside the body of a card without card-block.

```
<div class="container">
    <h5>
    The building block of a card is the .card-block. Use it whenever you need a padded section within a card.
    </h5>
    <h4>
    row inside card "body" with class card-block
    </h4>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Featured
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4>
    row inside card "body" without class card-block
    </h4>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Featured
        </div>
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="photo-box">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use padding for the body of my card

> The building block of a card is the .card-block. Use it whenever you need a padded section within a card.

but my grid comes out of the body of the card.
 
Is a desired behavior or is a bug to fix?

Thank you

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd2anwej/) (open full view)

Comment: I believe this is actually the desired behaviour - if you'll see that the row is 15px bigger than it's containing element each side left and right - in the .CSS you'll find that row has margin-left:-15px and margin-right:-15px ... that's minus 15px each side which is causing this 'weird' behaviour - you'll notice that the contained elements line up rather nicely if you were to remove the blue border from the [class^="col-"] element - this is the desired look in this instance

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is the desired behavior of the grid system. The `.row` has a negative margin to counteract the padding of grid columns, so that the leftmost and rightmost columns have proper alignment with the edge of the the viewport (or the edge of the `.row`'s container). Also, while the negative margin is there, the *content* of each grid column is still within the card because of the padding in each column.

Normally, the `.row` is placed inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid` that has 15px padding to counteract the negative margin. `.card-block` does have padding, but it's not 15px which is why the `.card-block` does not perfectly align the card's grid content to the edge of your `card`.

So, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but there are 2 other ways you could use the grid inside the `card`. One way, is to use a `.container-fluid` so that the outer grid columns align perfectly with the edge of the card...

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    ..
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    ..
                </div>
                ..
             </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

Another is to use a gutterless row (`.no-gutters`). This would remove the negative margin from the row, and padding from all of the columns. The content of each column then takes the entire width of the column.

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    ..
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    ..
                </div>
                ..
        </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/vE2EdNPQwV